# What is the difference between Bitnami and Click to deploy on GCE?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

Just trying to understand what's the difference between bitnami apps and google 'click-to-deploy' options on Google Cloud Engine?

For example: There is a ['Cassandra' click-to-deploy](https://cloud.google.com/launcher/solution/click-to-deploy-images/cassandra) and there is a [Bitnami version of 'Cassandra'](https://cloud.google.com/launcher/solution/bitnami-launchpad/cassandra)

Can anyone tell me how do they compare and what are the differences?
- is one restrictive compared to the other?
- does bitnami version lock you in somehow?
- is there any performance difference (other than obvious performance difference that the hardware change would bring)

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Bitnami](https://bitnami.com/) makes application stacks that run on several cloud platforms including Google Cloud Platform, AWS, Azure and a few others.  The Bitnami images you see on [Google Cloud Launcher](https://cloud.google.com/launcher/) are created by employees of Bitnami and are mostly standard across cloud.

Click to Deploy images are usually created by Google Cloud Platform employees working in conjunction with application vendors.

There are differences in versions here and there related to maintenance, but there isn't any difference in the way they are intended to be used.  Some Click to Deploy images will incur higher use charges due to licensing (ie. the Click to Deploy image contains the "Pro" version of a vendor's software), but these are called out during the selection process.

Neither version is intended to lock you into a particular platform, Google or Bitnami, it's just that there is duplication among the applications provided.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. To take an example of Cassandra, there's a massive price difference between the two options. Bitnami version being $14.20/month (cassandra version 3.0.0) and Click-to-Deploy (CTD) being $506/month (cassandra version 2.1.8). Also the Bitnami version is of 'single vm' type and the CTD version being 'multi vm'. So I am still not clear on the effective differences between them when it comes to the usage.

Comment: Clearly the cost difference is easily explained.  Bitnami solution in this case is clearly less powerful (VM Instance: g1-small $13.80/month) and just one node. The Click to deploy solution is a cluster of much more powerful machines (3 x VM Instance: n1-highmem-4 + 10GB Boot Disk).

Why you want a Cassandra single machine vs a cluster, is a bit outside of area of expertise, but this [post from the Cassandra FAQ](http://www.planetcassandra.org/blog/cassandra-faq-can-i-start-with-a-single-node/) is helpful.